# How to block frame resizing JFrame swing SeaGlass L&F

Tags: java, swing, resize, look-and-feel

I need for my next project a little better Look and Feel than that which java originally provide. I choosed to dive into [SeaGlass](http://seaglass.googlecode.com/svn/doc/index.html) L&F which seems to be pretty nice. However I encountered the problem. I can't prevent user of app from resizing and maximazing my JFrame. From what I found it is well-known issue in SeaGlass and it will be fixed in 2.1 version (what its stated [here](http://code.google.com/p/seaglass/issues/detail?id=88)). Unfortunately, last available version is 2.0 and it looks like this project is abandoned - last update is one year old. My question is: is there any work-around to stop user from resizing my JFrame? Maybe something with Mouse Listener?

FYI setUndecorated(true); is not working too.

Comment: This is Bug, no idea, presented in both version (my PC), doesn't works for me in Java7, hmmmm ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figuered it out.

JFrame must implement ComponentListener and in overridden componentResized method you must put that code:

```
setSize(410, 240);
setLocation(startLocation);
```